# How do I close out a .dialog window from JQuery UI without using the generated button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hey guys so in JQuery ui it produces a close link that once clicked it closes the dialog.  My question is how to I close it out without using that button?

I have a terms of service that pops up and I need the `decline terms` link to be used instead of the `close button` generated from the ui.

So let me know how I go about doing this, thanks :)

EDIT:

I used the following code and no cigar - tells me Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

```
function decline(){

     $( '#decline' ).dialog( 'close' );

    }
```

Once the selector is clicked it has a onclick="" which sends it here.  The selector is a id="decline"

Here is the entire code on my page which grabs the dialog -

```
$(function() {
        $( "dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
    });
    function showUrlInDialog(url){
      var tag = $("<div></div>");
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          tag.html(data).dialog
          ({
              width: '100%',
                modal: true
          }).dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }
    function agree(){
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    }
    function decline(){

     $( '#decline' ).dialog( 'close' );

    }
```

Here is the selector that will initialize it -

```
<a href="#" onclick="showUrlInDialog('termsofservice.php'); return false;">link to page B</a>
```

Here is the selector that I WANT to close the dialog box -

```
<a href="#" onclick="decline();" id="decline"><span >I decline these terms</span></a>
```

Edit -

Here is new code I am using with no sucess:

```
function decline(){

     $( '#terms-container' ).dialog( 'close' );

    }
```

## terms-container is the main div from the other file where the initilizer gets the data

Comment: Can you add the dialog initialization code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to close the dialog from somewhere else, I'd suggest creating a div which is there to take your html from the ajax call rather than creating it on the fly.
Html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showUrlInDialog('termsofservice.php'); return false;">link to page B</a>
<a href="#" onclick="decline();" id="decline"><span >I decline these terms</span></a>
<div id="dialog-container"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-container").dialog( "destroy" );
});
function showUrlInDialog(url){
  var tag = $("#dialog-container");
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      tag.html(data).dialog
      ({
          width: '100%',
            modal: true
      }).dialog('open');
    }
  });
}
function agree(){
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
}
function decline(){

 $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `$( '.dialog' ).dialog( 'close' );`

replacing '.dialog' with your selector

```
$( 'a#decline' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( this ).closest( '.ui-dialog' ).dialog( 'close' );
}) ;
```

since your code is set up using inline javascript, the above wont work. try chaning your decline function to this

```
function decline() {
 $( 'dialog:ui-dialog' ).dialog( 'close' );
 // OR THIS
 $( '.ui-dialog' ).children( 'div' ).eq( 0 ).dialog( 'close' );
}
```

Comment: gonna need more info from you, because with this code, the dialog should already be initialized... Assuming the link is in the modal

Comment: yeah, you are callign dialog( 'close' ) on the link. change it to the selector of the whole dialog

Comment: The dialog is not given to the <a id='decline' /> but to the div you're creating in the ajax call.

Comment: oh the main div in the other file - where it gets the content is a div named #terms-container  - do I use that?

Comment: yeah, the id of the dialog

Comment: try my edit. You really should read their docs on this too. Their documentation is really good

Comment: Ya no success with it...Ya I know I just learned about it and its cool!  You have any idea as to why its not working?

Comment: yeah, your dialog doesnt actually have a selector on it, so its not easy to get the selector.